# How to apply different functions to different rows of each matrix in a list?

Tags: r, list, function, matrix

I have a list holding a couple of matrices with the same amount of rows (4). Now I want to apply a function like log2(row/something) to say rows 1 and 4 and a function like log2(row/something else) to rows 2 and 3.

In code:

```
# Create list with 2 matrices with 4 rows
l<-list(a=matrix(1:16,nrow=4),b=matrix(17:32,nrow=4))

# Now I thought it might be possible to
nl <- lapply(l, function(x){
  log2(x[c(1,4),]/14)
  log2(x[2:3,]/23)
})
```

But the result is that only the last function in the `lapply`is executed. Also I thought it might be possible to:

```
nl <- l
lapply(nl, function(x) x[c(1,4),]) <- lapply(l, function(x) log2(x[c(1,4),]/14))
lapply(nl, function(x) x[2:3,]) <- lapply(l, function(x) log2(x[2:3,]/23))
```

But R really doesn't like that creative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first solution should work, only now the function only returns the last part. A little change should work?

```
l<-list(a=matrix(1:16,nrow=4),b=matrix(17:32,nrow=4))

nl <- lapply(l, function(x){
  x[c(1,4),] <- log2(x[c(1,4),]/14)
  x[2:3,] <- log2(x[2:3,]/23)
  return(x)
})
```

Comment: Oh, great. I also played around with a similar solution but I never got it quite right. Thanks a lot for that!

Comment: Decent solution -- tho' I note in passing that judicious use of `do.call` with a string variable like `myfuncs<-c('my_first_logfunc','mysecond_logfunc')` , and predefining `my_first_logfunc<-function(x) log2(x[c(1,4),]/14)`  would be a little cleaner.